# How can I use lucene's shingleanalyzerwrapper + standardanalyzer + indexreader?

Tags: java, lucene, tokenize, full-text-indexing, frequency-analysis

I hope you can help me with this problem.
What I intend to do:
Given a right text, I want to count the frequencies for every stemmized token ngrams without the stopwords(in other words, the stopwords are already removed).

This is the situation:
I am indexing some texts with IndexWriter using ShingleAnalyzerWrapper + StandardAnalyzer and when I add a document to IndexWriter(like this: indexwriter.addDocument(doc, analyzer); where analyzer is again, ShingleAnalyzerWrapper + StandardAnalyzer  ).

But the problem is:
When I get the term frequencies and the terms, the stopwords seem to be substituted by underlines.

This is the input:
String text = "to i want to to i want to linked";
String text2 = "super by by hard easy ";

This is the output:
term:*|freq:6

term:* _|freq:2  
term:_ hard|freq:1  
term:_ i|freq:2  
term:_ link|freq:1  
term:easy|freq:1  
term:hard|freq:1  
term:hard easy|freq:1  
term:i|freq:2  
term:i want|freq:2  
term:link|freq:1  
term:super|freq:1  
term:super _|freq:1
term:want|freq:2
term:want _|freq:2

If anything was unclear, please ask me so I try to make myself more clear

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please see http://www.lucidimagination.com/search/document/e5681676403a007b/can_i_omit_shinglefilter_s_filler_tokens for some solutions.

In this case it seems like you probably want to disable position increments on your stopfilter, as you don't want to introduce a "hole" where the stopword was, you want to pretend like they never existed.

Comment: The link gives a page not found; this appears to be the same discussion though: http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/lucene/java-user/123704?do=post_view_threaded#123704